Vue- problem with "missing semicolon" error
i'm learning vue and i have encountered annoying error [vue/compiler-sfc] Missing semicolon. in this portion of code:
export default {
    props: ['pageCreated'],
    data(){
        pageTitle: '',
        linkText: '',
        linkUrl: '',
        content: ''
    }
}

console highlights that linkText: '', is missing semicolon. How can i fix that?

Your JS is invalid, return an object:
export default {
    props: ['pageCreated'],
    data(){
      return {
        pageTitle: '',
        linkText: '',
        linkUrl: '',
        content: ''
      };
    }
}


Ok, it's time to take a break... Thank you for help!
